# Recover data from an Angular form with Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a problem since a few days. i'm sure it is very basic but I'm unable to find a solution.

I try to recover data sent by an Angular form into a java method with Spring. My code is the following :

App.js

```js
myController.prototype = {

    processForm : function processForm() {
        alert('foo!');
    },

    retrieveUrl : function retrieveUrl() {
        this.url.$ready = false;
        return this.http
            .post("/myURL", {data : this.formData})
            .then(function(response) {
               // do something
            }.bind(this), function(error) {
               // do something else
            }.bind(this));
    }
};
```

The value of formData :

```js
{data : 
   {"object1":
      {"prop1":"q",
      "prop2":"w"},
   "object2":
      {"prop3":"e",
      "prop4":"r"}
   }
}
```

And my Java code :

```js
@RequestMapping("/myURL")
    public void myController(@RequestBody  Form form) {
        System.out.println(form );
     }
```

I also have three beans, Form, Object1 and Object2, each with an empty contructor and the coresponding getters and setters.

Today, I enter in myController, the object form is not null but its two fields (object1 and object2) are null. So, I guess Spring doesn't understand that it needs to convert the data form into these two objects.

EDIT :

Thomas Pierre > Here is the code of my Form bean

```js
public class Form {

    public Object1 object1;

    public Object2 object2;

    public Form(){}

    public Object1 getObject1() {
        return object1;
    }

    public void setObject1(Object1 object1) {
        this.object1 = object1;
    }

     public Object2 getObject2() {
        return object2;
    }

    public void setObject2(Object2 object2) {
        this.object2 = object2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "BankForm [debitor = " + debtor +", bank = " + bank + "]";
    }
}
```

updated : "public final class" --> "public class"

Can't we use an Spring annotation to automatically make the deserialization ?

EDIT 2 : 
Here is my build.gradle file :

```js
buildscript {
 ext {
  springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
 }
 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
 }
 dependencies {
  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
// apply plugin: 'war'

jar {
 baseName = 'my-project'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
 maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
 providedRuntime
}

bootRun {
    // static classpath resources (i.e. in src/main/resources by default) are
    // reloadable in the live application
 addResources = true
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '1.7.2'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")


 compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    testCompile("junit:junit")

 testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

}
```

Object1.java :

```js
public class Object1 {

   public String prop1;

    public String prop2;

    public Object1(){}
  
    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp2(String prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    public String getProp2() {
        return prop2;
    }
}
```

Object2.java is exactly the same, just change the numbers. I checked twice there is no typing error or difference between the name of Form's, Object1's and Object2's fields and the names in formData returning by Angular.

I made a mistake by rewritting the JSON I recover in Java : there is some kind of "super object" called "data" which contains Object1 and Object2. Can't this be the problem ?

Comment: Add a which controller method which returns a populated Form instance as JSON (return the instance from the method and add @ResponseBody to the method). The JSON you are posting should be in the same format as is returned by this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Form class is final. I think that your using Jackson which use setters to create deserialize yout objet Form. As it is final, Jackson can't use setters to set objetct 1 and object2. And they are null

EDIT : 
Don't set your beans finals

EDIT 2 :

Update in your angular app :

`.post("/myURL", {data : this.formData})`

With :

```
.post("/myURL", this.formData)
```

This methods is waiting the object to send. By putting {data : this.formData}, you add a super object with a 'data' attribut.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work either... None of my beans are now final but the result is the same.

Comment: Which version of spring do you use ? Can you add you pom.xm and all your classes to the post please ?

Comment: I use SpringBoot in version 2.0.0. I do not have a pom.xml as I use gradle. But I can definitely post my build.gradle.

Comment: Ok, yes and your sources please.
SpringBoot 2.0 use Jackson, you can test serialization/deserialization with this unit test : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-json-tests

Comment: Thakns very much !

Answer (score 0):

Thomas is right.

But another approach might be with Gson serialization.

@RequestBody String string

In implementation i just do `obj = new Gson().fromJson(string, type);`

Comment: It doesn't work either. Do you have a working example with Angular, Gson and Spring somewhere ?

Comment: Still the same result? Form class created but with null Obj1 and Obj2?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.